# How to generate multivariate random variables given probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose you can generate uniformly distributed random numbers $x_i\in[a,b]$. To shape probability distribution of these numbers as you like using [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

But what if you need to get tuples of numbers $v_i=\{v_{i1},v_{i2},...,v_{iN}\}$, distributed by a given multivariate probability distribution $f:\mathbb R^N\to[0,\infty)$? How to shape tuples of uniformly distributed numbers to distribution of $f$?

I've devised the following procedure, and it intuitively seems to be correct. But I'm not sure how to prove it.

For simplicity, consider 3-tuple case, i.e. $v_i=\{x_i,y_i,z_i\}$.

1. Introduce probability distribution of $x$: $f_x(x)=\int_\mathbb R\int_\mathbb R f(x,y,z)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz$.
2. Generate value of $x=x_0$ using inverse transform sampling for $f_x$.
3. Introduce probability distribution of $y$: $f_y(y)=C_1\int_Vf(x_0,y,z)\,\mathrm dz$. This is something like "if $x=x_0$, then $y$ is distributed as $f_y(y)$".
4. Generate value of $y=y_0$ as in step 2 using $f_y$.
5. Introduce probability distribution of $z$: $f_z(z)=C_2f(x_0,y_0,z)$.
6. Generate value of $z=z_0$ as in step 2 using $f_z$.
7. The tuple $\{x_0,y_0,z_0\}$ is the generated variable.

The coefficients $C_1$ and $C_2$ above are meant to be chosen so that $f_y$ and $f_z$ had total probability of 1.

Is the above procedure actually correct? If yes, then how to prove that $\{x_0,y_0,z_0\}$ is indeed distributed as given by $f$?

Comment: As you surmised, your algorithm is correct.  For a more formal proof you should look up conditional probability density functions.